# How to send data between Node js and javascript in an html file

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am using an eye tracker and I want to create a website that displays this data in real time. I have the eye tracker notifying a Node js server and it provides data really consistently but when I used socket.io to send the data over it was buffering really slowly. I want a way to receive this data in a script in my index.html from the Node js server in real time or as close as possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: WebSocket is the fastest way for sending data, probably you're doing something wrong, try to show some code of what you've done.

Comment: Socket communication is definitely the quickest. However, sometimes it defers back from socket communication to polling, which takes longer especially with a large amount of data. Show us some of your socket.io code along with any console messages your receiving.

Comment: I have found 'ws' to be stable with good docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws   it worked great when I used it to stream binary typed buffers from a node server to get rendered in real time browser side  ...  however unrelated I did have to use a webworker to manage all the browser side websocket traffic so brower web audio api event loop would never get interrupted by such network traffic ... something to keep in back of your mind ... post your browser side and its matching server side websocket code ... min complete stand alone example so we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my solution in socket.io-streams. Here's what I did:

in the app.js:

```
var ss = require('socket.io-stream');
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.of('/data').on('connection', socket => {
   var eyeTracker = ...
   var listener = {
       ...
       onGazeData:function(gazeData){ //trigger for recieving a gaze location
         var s = new Readable()
         s._read = function() {};
         var stream = ss.createStream();
         toSend = gazeData.x + "," + gazeData.y
         s.push(toSend);
         s.pipe(stream);
         ss(socket).emit('gaze',stream);
       }
    }
    eyeTracker.setListener(listener);
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
}
```

and in the index.js (linked to index.html) I put:

```
var ss = require('socket.io-stream');
$(function(){
   var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/data'); //or where ever you are running
   socket.on('connect', function() {
      ss(socket).on('gaze', function(stream) {
         stream.on('data', function(data) {
            //do what you want with data
         })
       })
    });
    //other parts of script outside of socket
});
```

This solution was able to keep up with the data being streamed.